# Why can't I backup to a directory in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, access-rights

I am debugging an issue that deals with SQL Server backing up the database to a directory.

The application I am running launches with Administrator rights, which is set in the `app.manifest` file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

The application sets the initial directory to the default SQL Server backup directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup
```

The user is allowed to change the backup directory, and they can type it in, so something like this is typed:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup 12
```

Then the program then instruct SQL to back up to the directory using the stored procedure:

```
BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName TO DISK = @FilePath WITH NAME = @BackupName
```

Where:

- `@FilePath` is the directory the user selects
- `@BackupName` is `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.bak`

The call fails with:

> Operating system error 5 (access is denied).

So I did some investigation on the directory rights using icacls on the command line for the default SQL Server backup directory:

```
icacls .\backup 

CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F) 
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F) 
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F) 
MIKE-2K8-1\SQLServerMSSQLUser$mike-2k8-1$MSSQLSERVER:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Then again for the directory the user creates:

```
icacls .\backup 12

BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F) 
CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F) 
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F) 
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F) 
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX) 
MIKE-2K8-1\SQLServerMSSQLUser$mike-2k8-1$MSSQLSERVER:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

I can see the permissions are different for the `SQLServerMSSQLUser` depending upon the directory... how can I change the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the user account you're running the BACKUP DATABASE query under part of the db_backupoperator group?

Comment: The backup succeeds for the directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup  but fails for the very same user for this directory  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup 12  -- Nothing changes except the directory.

Comment: ok, give this a try:

icacls "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup 12" /grant:r "SQLServerMSSQLUser$mike-2k8-1$MSSQLSERVER":(OI)(CI)(I)(RX)M